# Redshift: How to add prefix on identity column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Has someone successfully tried to add a prefix to an auto generated identity column in redshift?

Comment: If it's a fixed prefix why not just `SELECT CONCAT('Prefix', id)`?

Comment: If it's always the same prefix, don't store it. Create a view that returns the concatenated value

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with simple alter command and it works on the identity column exactly same way as it does with other columns.

ALTER TABLE schema_name.table_name
RENAME COLUMN identity_column_name TO prefixed_new_column_name;

*Note:  identity_column_name like this IDENTITY ( seed, step )*

Let me know if you are asking for something else.